# Backbone Event are not clearing by undelegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have been working on backbone error where i am trying to clean up the events using undelegate also tried unbind. Actuually when i choose value from drop it create 3 grid that are drawn from the database. But when i click somewhere else and come again on the same and click the drop down it shows four flats.

I guessed its due to the ghost events are the issue hence tried below. But it doesnt seem to work. May i know where am getting wrong here.

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanking in advance

```
 var towersetupimageview = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : jQuery('#imageBlocksDiv'),

   events : {
           'keypress #no_of_towers' : 'totaltowers',
           'change .floortypedropdownfortowerfloor': 'showflatsinfloorwise',
           'click .saveflatdetails' : 'save_flat_details',
           'click .updateflatdetails' : 'update_flat_details',
    },
    template: _.template(jQuery('#towersviewaccordian').html()),
    cleanup: function() {
        alert()
        this.delegateEvents();
        jQuery(this.el).empty();

    },
    initialize : function(){

        _.bindAll(this, 'cleanup');


       // _.bindAll(this);



        this.cleanup();
        this.unbind();
        var that = this;
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.$el.append('<select style="float:left;padding:2px;" id="towersetupflats"></select>');  
        jQuery.ajax({
                'cache': false,
                'type':'GET',
                'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/content/'+jQuery('#towersetup').val()+'/sctowers',
                 success : function(response){
                        for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                                jQuery('#towersetupflats').append('<option value="'+response[i]['objectId']+'">'+response[i]['tower_name']+'</option>');
                        }
                        that.showflatsfortower(jQuery('#towersetupflats').val());
                }
        });
        jQuery('#towersetupflats').change(function(){ 
            jQuery('#towerflatsetview').html('');
            that.showflatsfortower(jQuery('#towersetupflats').val());
        });
    },

    showflatsfortower : function(towerid){
                var that = this;
                jQuery('#imageBlocksDiv').append('<div style="float: left;margin-left: -9%;margin-top: 5%;width: 92%" id="towerflatsetview"></div>');
                jQuery.ajax({
                    'cache': false,
                    'type':'GET',
                    'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/randomdata/sctowers/objectId/'+towerid,
                        success : function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            for(i=0;i<response[0]['no_of_floors'];i++){
                                    jQuery('#towerflatsetview').append('<br><br><div class="towersetupstyle"><div style="float:left;margin-top:17px;"><span id="floornumber">'+i+'</span></div><div ><select id="floortypedropdownfortowerfloor'+i+'" class="floortypedropdownfortowerfloor"><option>Select Floor Type</option></select></div></div>');
                            }
                            that.getfloortypename();
                        }
                }); 
    },
            getfloortypename : function(){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    'cache': false,
                    'type':'GET',
                    'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/content/'+jQuery('#towersetup').val()+'/scfloortype',
                        success : function(response1){
                                console.log(response1);
                               for(i=0;i<response1.length;i++){
                                       jQuery('.floortypedropdownfortowerfloor').append('<option value="'+response1[i]['objectId']+'">'+response1[i]['name']+'</option>');
                               }
                       }
                }); 
            },
            showflatsinfloorwise : function(ev){
                var currentselect = jQuery(ev.currentTarget).attr('id'); 
                var that = this;
                var pushflatid = [];
                var j = 1;
                var floor_no = 'id'+jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(1).find('#floornumber').text(); 
                jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('.inventory_field').remove();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        'cache': false,
                        'type':'GET',
                        'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/flatdetails/sc_flat/tower_object_id/'+jQuery('#towersetupflats').val()+'/floorplan_type_object_id/'+jQuery(ev.currentTarget).val()+'/floor_no/'+floor_no,
                        success : function(responses){
                           // console.log(responses);
                           var k = 1;
                            if(responses['error'] == "could not be found"){
                                jQuery.ajax({
                                        'type':'GET',
                                        'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/randomdata/scunitplan_on_floortype/floortype_object_id/'+jQuery('#'+currentselect).val(),
                                        success : function(responses1){
                                            for(var j = 0; j<responses1.length; j++){
                                                jQuery.ajax({
                                                    'type':'GET',
                                                    'url':jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/randomdata/scunitplantype/objectId/'+responses1[j]['unitplantype_object_id']+'',
                                                    success : function(newdata){
                                                             jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).append('<div class="inventory_field"><div class="flats_in_floor"><select class="update_unitplantypename"><option value="'+newdata[0]['objectId']+'">'+newdata[0]['name']+'</option></select></div></div>');
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                           that.getflatname(currentselect);  

                                        }
                                 });
                            }
                            else{
                                for(var i = 0; i<responses.length; i++){
                                    pushflatid.push(responses[i]['objectId']);
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                        'type':'GET',
                                        'url':jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/randomdata/scunitplantype/objectId/'+responses[i]['unitplan_object_id'],
                                        success : function(newdata){
                                                 jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).append('<div class="inventory_field" id="inventory_field'+j+'"><div class="flats_in_floor"><select class="update_unitplantypename"><option value="'+newdata[0]['objectId']+'">'+newdata[0]['name']+'</option></select></div></div>');
                                                 j++;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                       'cache': false,
                                       'type':'GET',
                                        'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/randomdata/sc_flat_common_fields_details/flat_object_id/'+responses[i]['objectId'],
                                        success : function(newres){
                                            for(var j=0; j<newres.length; j++){
                                                    jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('#inventory_field'+k).append('<div style="float:left;width:100%"><span style="width: 60px;float: left;margin: 5px;">'+newres[j]['common_field_name']+'</span><span style="margin:5px;float:left;"><input type="text" value="'+newres[j]['common_field_value']+'" id="'+newres[j]['objectId']+'" size="10" class="flat_common_field_value"><span></div>');
                                                    //jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('#inventory_field'+k+ ' .flat_common_field_value[data-objectid="'+inputid+'"]').attr('id',invfield[0]['objectId']);
                                                    if(j == "4"){ k++; }
                                            }
                                            var kval = (k-1);
                                            jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('#inventory_field'+kval).append('<div class="updateflatdetails">Update</div><div class="flat_common_loader"><img style="float:right" src="http://www.dwellar.com/portal/assets/icon/dots.gif"></div><div class="update_flat_message">Update Flat Details..</div>');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                //that.getflatdetails(currentselect,pushflatid);
                            }
                        }

                    });

            },
            getflatdetails : function(currentselect,flatid){
                var that = this;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    'cache': false,
                    'type':'GET',
                    'url':jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/content/'+jQuery('#towersetup').val()+'/sc_inventory_fieldconfigured',
                    success : function(invfield){
                        for(var k=0; k<invfield.length; k++){
                            jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('.inventory_field').append('<div style="float:left;width:100%;"><span style="width: 60px;float: left;margin: 5px;">'+invfield[k]['field_name']+'</span><span style="margin:5px;float:left;"><input type="text" size="10" id="'+invfield[k]['field_name']+'" data-objectid="'+invfield[k]['objectId']+'" class="flat_common_field_value" onload="'+that.myFunction(flatid,invfield[k]['objectId'],currentselect)+'"></span></div>');
                        }
                        jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('.inventory_field').append('<div class="updateflatdetails">Update</div><div class="flat_common_loader"><img style="float:right" src="http://www.dwellar.com/portal/assets/icon/dots.gif"></div><div class="update_flat_message">Update Flat Details..</div>');
                    }
                });
            },
            myFunction : function(flatid,inputid,currentselect){
                var j = 1;
                for(var n = 0; n<flatid.length; n++){
                  jQuery.ajax({
                      'cache': false,
                      'type':'GET',
                      'url':jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/newrandomdata/sc_flat_common_fields_details/flat_object_id/'+flatid[n]+'/common_field_object_id/'+inputid,
                      success : function(invfield){
                          jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('#inventory_field'+j+ ' .flat_common_field_value[data-objectid="'+inputid+'"]').val(invfield[0]['common_field_value']);
                          jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('#inventory_field'+j+ ' .flat_common_field_value[data-objectid="'+inputid+'"]').attr('id',invfield[0]['objectId']);
                          j++;
                      }   
                  });
                }
            },
            getflatname : function(currentselect){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    'type':'GET',
                    'url':jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/authentication/content/'+jQuery('#towersetup').val()+'/sc_inventory_fieldconfigured',
                    success : function(invfield){
                        //console.log(invfield.length);
                        for(var k=0; k<invfield.length; k++){
                            jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('.inventory_field').append('<div style="float:left;width:100%;"><span style="width: 60px;float: left;margin: 5px;">'+invfield[k]['field_name']+'</span><span style="margin:5px;float:left;"><input type="text" size="10" id="'+invfield[k]['field_name']+'" data-objectid="'+invfield[k]['objectId']+'" class="flat_common_field_value"></span></div>');
                        }
                             jQuery('#'+currentselect).parents().eq(1).find('.inventory_field').append('<div class="saveflatdetails">Save</div><div class="flat_common_loader"><img style="float:right" src="http://www.dwellar.com/portal/assets/icon/dots.gif"></div><div class="save_flat_message">Flat Details Saved..</div>');
                    }
                });
            },

            save_flat_details : function(ev){
                var currentbuton = ev.currentTarget;
                jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_loader').show();
                var fl = jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_field_value').length;
                var ij = 0;
                    var fieldinputData = {
                            'tower_object_id' : jQuery('#towersetupflats').val(),
                            'floor_no' : 'id'+jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(1).find('#floornumber').text(),
                            'floorplan_type_object_id' : jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(1).find('.floortypedropdownfortowerfloor').val(),
                            'unitplan_object_id' : jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.update_unitplantypename').val(),
                            'projectId' : jQuery('#towersetup').val(),
                    };
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        'type':'POST',
                        'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/example/content/sc_flat',
                        'data' : fieldinputData,
                        success : function(field){
                            console.log(field);

                                jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_field_value').each(function(){
                                    var fieldinputData = {
                                            'flat_object_id' : field.objectId,
                                            'projectId' : jQuery('#towersetup').val(),
                                            'common_field_object_id' : jQuery(this).attr('data-objectid'),
                                            'common_field_value' : jQuery(this).val(),
                                            'common_field_name' : jQuery(this).attr('id')
                                    };
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                        'type':'POST',
                                        'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/example/content/sc_flat_common_fields_details',
                                        'data' : fieldinputData,
                                        success : function(response){
                                            console.log(response)
                                            jQuery(currentbuton).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_loader').hide();
                                            if(fl/ij == "1"){
                                                jQuery(currentbuton).parents().eq(0).find('.save_flat_message').show();
                                                jQuery(currentbuton).parents().eq(0).find('.save_flat_message').fadeOut(3000);
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });
                                    ij++;
                                });
                        }
                    }); 

            },
            update_flat_details : function(ev){
                jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_loader').show();
                var currentbuton = ev.currentTarget;
                var ij = 0;
                var fl = jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_field_value').length;
                jQuery(ev.currentTarget).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_field_value').each(function(){
                    var fieldinputData = {
                            'common_field_value' : jQuery(this).val()
                    };
                    fieldinputData.id = (jQuery(this).attr('id') != null) ? jQuery(this).attr('id'):"";
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        'type':'POST',
                        'url': jQuery('#baseurl').val()+'index.php/api/example/content/sc_flat_common_fields_details',
                        'data' : fieldinputData,
                        success : function(response){
                            console.log(response)
                            jQuery(currentbuton).parents().eq(0).find('.flat_common_loader').hide();
                            if(fl/ij == "1"){
                                jQuery(currentbuton).parents().eq(0).find('.update_flat_message').show();
                                jQuery(currentbuton).parents().eq(0).find('.update_flat_message').fadeOut(3000);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    ij++;
                });
            }


 });
```

Comment: Hi mu is too short thanks for reply but the issue is not with that drop down issue is with floortypedropdownfortowerfloor when you go on other page and come again it will duplicate the events. I have dited the code extended it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're manually binding a change-handler here:

```
jQuery('#towersetupflats').change(function(){ ... });
```

[`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) only removes events bound to the view's `el` through [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) (i.e. events from the view's `events`).

You should be binding all your events in `events`:

```
events : {
    //...
    'change #towersetupflats': 'some_function'
},
some_function: function() {
    this.$('#towerflatsetview').html('');
    this.showflatsfortower(this.$('#towersetupflats').val());
}
```